# What's the difference between "got used to" and "was getting used to"?

Tags: grammar

What's the difference between "got used to" and "was getting used to"?
I got used to driving on the left.
I was getting used to driving on the left.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of [past simple vs. past continuous](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/beginner-grammar/past-continuous-and-past-simple). The first describes a completed action, the other describes one still in progress.

> I got used to driving on the left.

The speaker is now used to driving on the left. That process is finished.

> I was getting used to driving on the left.

At the time being spoken about, the speaker was still not 100% used to driving on the left, but they were working on it.

Where some people get tripped up is when the continuous is used to mean an action is *almost* or *pretty much* completed - the difference between

> Throughout January, I was getting used to driving on the left

and

> By February, I was getting used to driving on the left

This is still different from past simple in that however close the action is to completion, it still isn't there yet.